# Can a python function be called from a website by clicking on a link of that page?

Tags: python, html

I have a website powered by python (index.html) which its content is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3

    def EchoHello():
        print ('Hello')

    d = '''
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Project List</h2>

        <table>
         <tr><th>Active Projects</center></th></tr>
         <tr><td>Line</td><td>Proj ID</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="/EchoHello()">Proj100</a></td><td>Calculate ID</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''

    print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print (d)
```

I would like to run the function EchoHello() when someone clicks on the Proj100 link on the website. I know I can create another script outside this one, but I would like to keep these small functions within the same website code. Is this a possibility just using python and html? I do not want to use javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need "PyScript", but I need to explain first that there is no way to directly let Python interact with HTML, even if you use flask.
You can view and download this library on the official website of PyScript.
And put the css and js files of PyScript in the same directory.
Here is a code example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pyscript.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-repl></py-repl>
        <script src="pyscript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/python">
            print("Hello, world!")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pyscript.html

Comment: Hmmmm... If it is not possible to do that, I have to keep designing. Thanks.

Comment: ? I'm not gathering why that suggested to you it wasn't possible. Maybe a more complete example in context will show you it is possible. If you go here](https://pyscript.net/examples/) and click on the tile that says 'PyScript Native TODO App".  You'll see there is a button that let's you add tasks. The code for that HTML page is [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/examples/todo-pylist.html). Line 65 and other lines clearly have the use of functions. Pyscript can be linked to Javascript and with Javascript you can ...

Comment: <continued>  [Execute a javascript function by clicking on text](https://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0069.html). I think all the pieces are in place to do what you describe with HTML using pyscript? It doesn't matter that your site is powered by Python. You won't be using that to execute the python that Pyscript runs. Pyscript actually runs Python on the user's machine inside the browser like a virtual system. On the other hand, with Flask and Django you can use HTML and javascript abilities in conjunction with Python running on your server that hosts the site. But as SN-Grotesque points ...

Comment: <continued> it isn't as simple as just mish-mashing the two languages together. At least not for Django, and I doubt for Flask.

Comment: Thanks. I was more looking for an HTML and python connection. I know I can use forms, and trick the program like that. However, I was looking for the python <==> HTML bidirectional communication. Thanks.